# Why is pip install not working with Spyder 5?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've upgraded from Spyder 4 to Spyder 5 with Anaconda this weekend due to lag issues with Spyder 4 on Mac. However previous programs I have written won't run due to not having packages (yfinance, matplotlib.pyplot) installed. When I use the standard 'pip install yfinance' command it returns 'no module named pip'. I have reinstalled pip with terminal multiple times and confirmed it is there, and pip install still works on Spyder 4. I have also deleted and redownloaded Spyder 5 multiple times and updated to the latest MacOS software.

Has anyone had a similar issue or got any ideas how to fix this? My dissertation is due soon and cant afford to lose any more days on this!! Thanks in advance...

Comment: which python version your using??

Comment: I'm on version 3.8.8 at the moment

Comment: new Spyder may use different Python and you may have installed modules in one Python and run code with different Python. Pythons doesn't share modules and you have to install again modules in new Python. OR you have to check in `Spyder` settings what Python it uses and compare with python used to install modules `python -V`

Comment: maybe first in spyder run `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python`  and later use it to install modules `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...`